# When do we use *to + ing*? "He confessed to killing Kem over a $3,000 debt"

Tags: gerunds, infinitive-vs-gerund

When do we use *to + ing* (gerund)? is the following form commonly used?

> Later, he confessed to **killing** Kem over a $3,000 debt. A Cambodian court charged him with premeditated murder. Authorities considered the case cut-and-dried ... [Los Angeles Times](http://www.latimes.com/world/asia/la-fg-cambodia-chevron-2016-story.html)

Can we use "He confessed he **killed** Kem ..."? or Is the above form more fluent?

**Update:**

I want to know when we use *to + ing* (gerund) in general. the "confessed to" is just an example.

Comment: In regards to this specific example, it's about style. This being a newspaper article, I can see an argument for using "to killing" because it sounds more objective instead of the "he confessed he [had] killed," which sounds more subjective.

Comment: There's no difference in meaning, but the gerund-participial "killing Kem ..." is the most natural. Note that "killing" is verb, not a noun, as evidenced by the fact that it has a direct object "Kem".

Comment: @BillJ, in this context, **killing** is a gerund, a verb that functions as a noun in a sentence. A gerund can take a direct object, for example **Eating people is wrong.**.

Comment: @JavaLatte Nouns never take direct objects, only verbs do. "Killing" is clearly a verb since it can take an adverbial modifier: "He confessed to viciously killing Kem", but nouns cannot (normally) be modified by adverbs. Same with "eating people": "people" is object of "killing" and again an adverb is possible: "Needlessly eating people is wrong". (Note, though,  that they can be nouns, as in "He confessed to the killing of Kem" and "The eating of people is wrong".) Complementation is a good indicator.

Comment: @BillJ:  (sigh).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short Answer:

It's about style and tone.

Long Answer:

I can tell you that to me, "to killing" sounds more formal than "he [had] killed" and so, in the context of a newspaper article, it makes more sense.

Also, when reporting in a newspaper article about an event such as this one, you usually want to strike a more objective tone as the writer and "distance" yourself from the subject of the article.

Using "to killing" instead of "he confessed he [had] killed" achieves this effect.

Lastly, while some words have forms they always use, e.g., "avoid 'killing,'" versus "avoid 'to kill,'" in this case, it's just a matter of style and tone.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/confess), it is normal to follow **confess** with either **that** and a clause or **to** and a noun... and a gerund is effectively a noun form of a verb.

> He confessed that he killed Kem
>   He confessed to murder
>   He confessed to killing Kem.

In informal speech it is possible to omit the **that**, but it would be a bit slack to do so in formal writing.

Answer (score 0):

> **Confess to is what is variously called a phrasal verb** or a preposition verb phrase or a prepositional phrasal verb: a combination VERB + PREPOSITION which acts together as a VERB. It takes a Direct Object, which must be a noun or noun phrase.
>
> Accordingly, if you employ a verbal form as the object, it must be a gerund: a verbal form which acts as a noun:
>
> > He **confessed to having** a secret admiration for his opponent.
> >     [Why is a gerund used after the verb “confess to”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104160/why-is-a-gerund-used-after-the-verb-confess-to)

Comment: Same applies to a more popular example. `I'm lookong forward to hearing from you.`